# BufferWriter writing to a file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

The following program  reads from the file and writes to the output file
.This works perfectly fine but i wonder why is it working correctly.Isn't supposed to add an extraLine at the end of file? But why is it working fine.please explain its behaviour

InputFile:

abcdefg

def

The input is newline + abcdefg +newline+def and thats it! 
As per the code it is supposed to add an extra line at the end but its just working fine.

---

```
try (
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(new File("/home/admins/Desktop/Sources/src/input.txt")));
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(new File("/home/admins/Desktop/Sources/src/output.txt")))) {
    String c = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (c != null) {
        bufferedWriter.write(c+"\n");
        c=bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Comment: **Why** *would* it? You write one line per call to `readLine`.

Comment: bufferedReader.readLine();  would just give the string without \n ,then i am adding the new Line to write it into the file.But for the last line ,is it not supposed to add a line more?

Comment: Be sure that you use a tool like `hexedit` to *look at* the content of the output-file, byte-by-byte, to see what is actually there.  With the code as written, I would expect to see each line that was read from the input, followed by a newline.  (But, what if the string as-read already contains newline?)  So, the fastest way to get to the bottom of your problem is to use a tool such as this, which will *show you* the "invisible" bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You **are** printing a new line character. If you continued to write to the file, the content would be in the following line.

It's not clear if you expect an explicit empty line in your output, but if you write to the file following the while loop, it'll be on the line after `def`.

You may want to additionally `trim` the input line from the file before you write it to remove other whitespace, non-printable characters.

You could also put an if statement around the write to check for empty lines so you can skip them

Comment: yes i am expecting an  empty line in the output,but thats not happening.Say if have 2 empty lines after def then the following code is exatly writing 2 lines after def and exiting the code.but i thought there must be a flaw and should print an extra line

Comment: Your code never prints an empty line, though, only moves the file pointer to the start of the next line after you write to it

Answer (score -1):

Use the newspace technique when you are reading from the file too. Like,

```
while(c != 0){
    fileOutputStream = ("/n" + c); /*then read it as...*/    
    c = "/n" + fileInputStream.readLine();
}
```

Comment: can u please elaborate the answer?

Comment: Is `c` an integer or a number? I don't think this compiles